# How to perform JMETER Multiple threads doing multiple actions?

Tags: jmeter

I have an requirement of creating test plan in jmeter

User 1 ==> 10 threads  ==> 1st thread login into a GUI and edit 1st line , 2nd thread will edit 2nd line and so on till 5th thread for 5th line again same scenario continues till it reaches 10 thread.

How do we use CSV or parameterized concept to answer above use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use any external parameterization like CSV files for this.

JMeter provides [__threadNum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) which returns the current thread (virtual user) number so if you want 1st user to edit the 1st line - just use `${__threadNum}` function in the place where you need to provide the line number and that would be it.

[image]

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)